# Is there a way - with google scripts - to authomatically check if the note field in a recurring event is empty

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are a non profit association running a library. We use a shared calendar to program the opening hours (and the volunteers who keep the library open). We need a way to be automatically notified (by email best) if a day is with no volunteers. We use the note field for this purpose, so we need to know if for a particular day the note field is empty and in that case a mail should be sent to all the volunteers.
I'm no programmer, just trying with google scrips, but looking at the various examples I found many creating events functions, but no way to check the note field of an event. So before smashing my head I would like to know if that is possible :-)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.